# Finding the Center Line from a set of 3D Points

Tags: algorithm, 3d

I have a set of 3D points. They follow a curved pattern with a rather constant diameter as shown below. What would be the algorithm to trace the approximate center line of these points?

[image: 3d Points]

Comment: Polynomial 3rd degree, Excel?

Comment: What sort of tools are you using or do you have available? Matlab? Excel? R? Python?

Comment: @ScottNewson - definitely not Matlab.I am open to any programming language.

Comment: This question/answer could help you, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208554/calculate-centerline-in-3d-structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208554/calculate-centerline-in-3d-structure)

Answer (score 7):

There is a paper called ["Curved Reconstruction from Unorganized Points"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.56.1432&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by In-Kwon Lee which looks into constructing lines/curves from a set of points without any ordering by exploiting the [moving least-squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_least_squares) method. Although it focues on 2D applications, it mentions the possibility of extending this to higher dimensions. The following image is taken from the paper:

[image: Images taken from mentioned-paper]

In '**Chapter 4 - 3D Extension**', it describes how the method cannot be applied directly to 3 dimentions but it is possible to compute a 3D quadratic regression curve by:

- Grouping neighbouring points using the moving least-squares method
- Computing a regression plane **K** : z = A*x* + B*y* + C by minimizing a quadratic
- Projecting those neighbouring points to plane **K** and solving the 2D moving least-squares problem.

Hope this helps! (Quite an interesting paper!)

Comment: @whuber - Thanks for checking. I edited my post as I coincidentally found a paper which may describe a possible method.

Comment: Nice find!  The EMST is a good choice on which to base a solution. (+1)  The procedure in that paper might be improved via robust smoothing methods such as Loess or various forms of penalized spline fits.

Answer (score 3):

This question has been already answered. Here is the same question:

[curve-fitting-3d-data-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588438/curve-fitting-3d-data-set)

If you are looking for ready to use tools and codes, there are many numerical methods to solve this problem, like greedy approach which is implemented in R packages, downloadble from [GAM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gam/).

If you are looking for pure algorithms to implement it yourself, I suggest you to ask it in math community (http://math.stackexchange.com)

Furthermore this wiki page is related to your question (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting)